# How to show Valid or Invalid Snackbar when user enters the credential in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When the user enter wrong credentials the snackbar should show Login Failed and when right page should show successfully logged in snackbar.
I have used firebase to authentication.

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _emailLoginFormTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordLoginFormTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _signInUsingFirebase(String email, String password) {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .then((AuthResult authResult) {
      FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HomePage(email: email, userid: user.uid,),
      ));
    }).catchError((error) {
      debugPrint(error);
    });
  }

  Widget _loginPageSaffoldBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailLoginFormTextEditingController,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passwordLoginFormTextEditingController,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // If statement is validating the input fields.
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _signInUsingFirebase(_emailLoginFormTextEditingController.text,
                    _passwordLoginFormTextEditingController.text);
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(                          //Snackbar for Succesfull
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text(
                      "Succesfull",
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              else{
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(                        //Snackbar for unsuccesfull
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text(
                      "Unsuccesfull",
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.lock_open,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 4),
                Text(
                  "Submit",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), // Submit Button
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

A little out of context question I also want to keep user logged in once they enter the credentials till they login in i want to use shared preference but unable to understand how if u can provide any link might help 
Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

For start, check the official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars), where some basic examples provided by Google itself.

In your case, retrieve the response of the Firebase Login and push it to the separate service, which will create the needed snack bar.

For the saving login - yes, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and save two separate strings - one for login, one for the password. When initially logged in, save those, and when a user opens an app once again, first check shared_preferences for the case of needed data, and if it exists - just push it to function

Feel free to ask anything :3

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Key:- `key:_scaffoldKey,` in scaffold

Declare `final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

Then simply initialize it in `.catchError((error)` and `.then((AuthResult authResult)`

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Succesfully LoggedIn"));
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```